# Assign one column value to other column in polars python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-polars

In polars pandas want to inter change/ assign , & inter change row value in two rows.

```
for i in range(len(k2)):
    k2['column1'][i] == k2['column2'][i]
    k2['column3'][i] == k2['column4'][i]
```

Comment: `k2.with_columns([pl.col("column1").alias("column3"),pl.col("column3").alias("column1")])` may be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `alias` to copy & rename columns:

```py
import polars as pl

k2 = pl.DataFrame({"column1": [1,2,3],
                   "column2": [4,5,6],
                   "column3": [7,8,9],
                   "column4": [10,11,12]})
```

```
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ column1 ┆ column2 ┆ column3 ┆ column4 │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ 1       ┆ 4       ┆ 7       ┆ 10      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2       ┆ 5       ┆ 8       ┆ 11      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3       ┆ 6       ┆ 9       ┆ 12      │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

```py
k2.with_columns([pl.col("column2").alias("column1"), pl.col("column4").alias("column3")])
```

which prints out

```
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ column1 ┆ column2 ┆ column3 ┆ column4 │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ 4       ┆ 4       ┆ 10      ┆ 10      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5       ┆ 5       ┆ 11      ┆ 11      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6       ┆ 6       ┆ 12      ┆ 12      │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: I got something like we can filter data frame features and store in a new variable then swap like :-                                                                                                                                k2['col1'] = k2['col3']
k2['col2'] = k2['col4']